# Ajax unexpected token error not fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not sure why I am getting an error after setTimeout of having an unexpected token. All I was doing with my ajax to throw an error if there is else reload the webpage after few seconds

```
    function submitFeedback(e){
//        var div = $(element).closest("div");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
        {
        type: "POST",
        url:  "../submitFeedback.php/",
        data: {
                userid: $("[name=changepasswordID]").val(),
                feedback: $("[name=submitfeedback]").val()
        },
        success: function(result)
        {
            if(result.success == true)
            {
                setTimeout(function()
                    {// wait for 5 secs(2)
                        location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                    }, 5000),
            },
                error: function(result)
            {
                    $(".feedbackstatusdisplay").html(result);
            } 
    }
        });
    };
```

Comment: `dataType: "json"` in the call config? Response is probably a string and not parsed as object.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Your code is indented wrong..... error should be on same level with success, but you have it with the if.... I am not sure why you have commas all over the place. There should not be one after the timeout

Comment: @epascarello what the best way to do it then?

Comment: Fix the code so it is correct?

Comment: @CumminUp07 unexpected token near set timeout in the console window

Comment: The error is inside of the success method.... This is where properly indenting your code is important.

Comment: Can we see your code please ?

Comment: @MichaelChu Please don't remove the code from the question. I've rolled back your edit which did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` callback should be at the same level as the success callback.

```
function submitFeedback(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../submitFeedback.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        userid: $("[name=changepasswordID]").val(),
        feedback: $("[name=submitfeedback]").val()
      },
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.success == true) {
          setTimeout(function () {// wait for 5 secs(2)
            location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
          }, 5000);
        }
      },
      error: function (result) {
        $(".feedbackstatusdisplay").html(result);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Still has issues.